# Динамическое преобразование примитивных типов

Tags: c#

В С# можно привести, например, переменную типа `float` к типу `int`, при этом значение будет урезано так, чтобы оно поместилось в переменную нового типа.

```
float a = 1;
int b = (int)a;
```

Но у меня сложилась такая ситуация, что я использую рефлексию, и тип необходимо привести в процессе выполнения программы.

Как это можно сделать, и возможно ли вообще?
Какие типы можно так приводить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, используйте [метод `Convert.ToInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/23511zys(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
object[] values = { true, -12, 163, 935, 'x', new DateTime(2009, 5, 12),
                    "104", "103.0", "-1",
                    "1.00e2", "One", 1.00e2, 16.3e42};
int result;

foreach (object value in values)
{
   try {
      result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
      Console.WriteLine("Converted the {0} value {1} to the {2} value {3}.",
                        value.GetType().Name, value,
                        result.GetType().Name, result);
   }
   catch (OverflowException) {
      Console.WriteLine("The {0} value {1} is outside the range of the Int32 type.",
                        value.GetType().Name, value);
   }                     
   catch (FormatException) {
      Console.WriteLine("The {0} value {1} is not in a recognizable format.",
                        value.GetType().Name, value);
   }
   catch (InvalidCastException) {
      Console.WriteLine("No conversion to an Int32 exists for the {0} value {1}.",
                        value.GetType().Name, value);

   }
}                           
// The example displays the following output:
//    Converted the Boolean value True to the Int32 value 1.
//    Converted the Int32 value -12 to the Int32 value -12.
//    Converted the Int32 value 163 to the Int32 value 163.
//    Converted the Int32 value 935 to the Int32 value 935.
//    Converted the Char value x to the Int32 value 120.
//    No conversion to an Int32 exists for the DateTime value 5/12/2009 12:00:00 AM.
//    Converted the String value 104 to the Int32 value 104.
//    The String value 103.0 is not in a recognizable format.
//    Converted the String value -1 to the Int32 value -1.
//    The String value 1.00e2 is not in a recognizable format.
//    The String value One is not in a recognizable format.
//    Converted the Double value 100 to the Int32 value 100.
//    The Double value 1.63E+43 is outside the range of the Int32 type.
```

Comment: а как быть, если я не знаю к какому типу мне нужно привести? так как приведение выполняется динамически, то и приводить, возможно, придется не только к `int` но и к `byte`, `short` или другим числовым типам.

Comment: Тогда используйте `Convert.ChangeType`, у него второй параметр - выходной тип. Рефлексией определяете какой тип вам нужен и передаете его в этот метод...

Comment: В том и проблема, что это я уже пробовал. При попытке конвертировать float в int выдает исключение о невозможности привести типы.

Comment: Не верю! Всё работает: `object a = (float)10; object b = Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(int)); Console.WriteLine($"{b} Type: {b.GetType()}");`

Comment: обожаю программирование) Ваш код работает.